# Seaborn Graph - plot NOT starting at (0,0)

Tags: python, seaborn

How do i make my graph begin at (0,0) by default? I have the problem throughout every graphicla plot using seaborn

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=titanic,col='sex')
g.map(plt.hist,'age')
```

[image]

Comment: Show some code that reproduces the issue

Comment: Sorry: 
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=titanic,col='sex')
g.map(plt.hist,'age')

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to set the x limits of the current axes:

```
plt.xlim(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a non-global change that wouldn't affect all plots in your script but rather just a single axes, there is [`ax.margins()`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html)